# Forgot Password showing 401 (Unauthorized) error

Tags: strapi

I am trying to use forgot password function from strapi's Authentication documentation. When trying to send forgot password request to the api returning an 401 error. I am using vue js as frontend framework.

```
<template>
<form @submit.prevent="onForgetPassword">
   <label for="name">your email</label>
    <input type="email" class="from-input" placeholder="Enter Your Email..." v-model="email"/>
    <button type="submit" class="form-btn">reset password</button>
 </form>
</template>

data() {
    return {
      email: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onForgetPassword() {
      axios
        .post("http://localhost:1337/auth/forgot-password", {
          email: this.email
        })
        .then(response => {
          // Handle success.
          console.log("Your user received an email");
        })
        .catch(error => {
          // Handle error.
          console.log("An error occurred:", error);
        });
    }
  }
```

Comment: please update your question correctly. we can't solve you by seeing your post request provide lil more code in question

Comment: @prasannapurohit Can you please check now.

Comment: sir i need your backend code for this.

Comment: For backend i dont have any sir.

Comment: without backend how you are connecting with database?

Comment: I am using strapi as my back-end and I am using MySQL as my local database. From my vue js front-end I can successfully create a new user and with that user i can login in to my frontend. When the user is created I can see it in the user's tab in strapi But When I am trying to use forgot password for a registered user it's giving me an error of 401